# Regarding the quantity of data which PyOD can handle

Tags: python, outliers

Recently, I have three samples. One sample contains around 2300 rows, the script works. However, when I import another sample which has more than 3500 rows, the script doesn't work and has following error message. Does it mean the script has limitation of data or is there some mistake in my script? Please do me a favor and any feedback will be great helpful.

Script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as matplotlib
from scipy import stats
from pyod.models.abod import ABOD
from pyod.models.cblof import CBLOF
from pyod.models.feature_bagging import FeatureBagging
from pyod.models.hbos import HBOS
from pyod.models.iforest import IForest
from pyod.models.knn import KNN
from pyod.models.lof import LOF
df = pd.read_csv("D:/1/PyOD sample 2.csv")
df.plot.scatter('Location','Value')
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
df[['Location','Value']] = scaler.fit_transform(df[['Location','Value']])
df[['Location','Value']].head()
X1 = df['Location'].values.reshape(-1,1)
X2 = df['Value'].values.reshape(-1,1)
X = np.concatenate((X1,X2),axis=1)
random_state = np.random.RandomState(42)
outliers_fraction = 0.05
classifiers = {
'Angle-based Outlier Detector (ABOD)': ABOD(contamination=outliers_fraction),
'Cluster-based Local Outlier Factor (CBLOF)':CBLOF(contamination=outliers_fraction,check_estimator=False, random_state=random_state),
'Feature Bagging':FeatureBagging(LOF(n_neighbors=35),contamination=outliers_fraction,check_estimator=False,random_state=random_state),
'Histogram-base Outlier Detection (HBOS)': HBOS(contamination=outliers_fraction),
'Isolation Forest': IForest(contamination=outliers_fraction,random_state=random_state),
'K Nearest Neighbors (KNN)': KNN(contamination=outliers_fraction),
'Average KNN': KNN(method='mean',contamination=outliers_fraction)
}
xx , yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1 , 200), np.linspace(0, 1, 200))

for i, (clf_name, clf) in enumerate(classifiers.items()):
clf.fit(X)
scores_pred = clf.decision_function(X) * -1
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
n_inliers = len(y_pred) - np.count_nonzero(y_pred)
n_outliers = np.count_nonzero(y_pred == 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
dfx = df
dfx['outlier'] = y_pred.tolist()
IX1 = np.array(dfx['Location'][dfx['outlier'] == 0]).reshape(-1,1)
IX2 = np.array(dfx['Value'][dfx['outlier'] == 0]).reshape(-1,1)
OX1 = dfx['Location'][dfx['outlier'] == 1].values.reshape(-1,1)
OX2 = dfx['Value'][dfx['outlier'] == 1].values.reshape(-1,1)
print('OUTLIERS : ',n_outliers,'INLIERS : ',n_inliers, clf_name)
threshold = stats.scoreatpercentile(scores_pred,100 * outliers_fraction)
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]) * -1
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
# fill blue map colormap from minimum anomaly score to threshold value
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, levels=np.linspace(Z.min(), threshold, 7),cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)
    
# draw red contour line where anomaly score is equal to thresold
a = plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, levels=[threshold],linewidths=2, colors='red')
    
# fill orange contour lines where range of anomaly score is from threshold to maximum anomaly score
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, levels=[threshold, Z.max()],colors='orange')
    
b = plt.scatter(IX1,IX2, c='white',s=20, edgecolor='k')

c = plt.scatter(OX1,OX2, c='black',s=20, edgecolor='k')
   
plt.axis('tight')  

# loc=2 is used for the top left corner 
plt.legend(
    [a.collections[0], b,c],
    ['learned decision function', 'inliers','outliers'],
    prop=matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(size=20),
    loc=2)
plt.xlim((0, 1))
plt.ylim((0, 1))
plt.title(clf_name)
plt.show()
```

Error Message

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\1\PyOD.py in line 69
     66 plt.axis('tight')  
     68 # loc=2 is used for the top left corner 
---> 69 plt.legend(
     70     [a.collections[0], b,c],
     71     ['learned decision function', 'inliers','outliers'],
     72     prop=matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(size=20),
     73     loc=2)
     74 plt.xlim((0, 1))
     75 plt.ylim((0, 1))

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py:2710, in legend(*args, **kwargs)
   2708 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.legend)
   2709 def legend(*args, **kwargs):
-> 2710     return gca().legend(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py:318, in Axes.legend(self, *args, **kwargs)
    316 if len(extra_args):
    317     raise TypeError('legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments')
--> 318 self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
    319 self.legend_._remove_method = self._remove_legend
    320 return self.legend_

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py:454, in make_keyword_only..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    448 if len(args) > name_idx:
    449     warn_deprecated(
    450         since, message="Passing the %(name)s %(obj_type)s "
    451         "positionally is deprecated since Matplotlib %(since)s; the "
    452         "parameter will become keyword-only %(removal)s.",
    453         name=name, obj_type=f"parameter of {func.__name__}()")
--> 454 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py:583, in Legend.__init__(self, parent, handles, labels, loc, numpoints, markerscale, markerfirst, reverse, scatterpoints, scatteryoffsets, prop, fontsize, labelcolor, borderpad, labelspacing, handlelength, handleheight, handletextpad, borderaxespad, columnspacing, ncols, mode, fancybox, shadow, title, title_fontsize, framealpha, edgecolor, facecolor, bbox_to_anchor, bbox_transform, frameon, handler_map, title_fontproperties, alignment, ncol, draggable)
    580 self._alignment = alignment
    582 # init with null renderer
--> 583 self._init_legend_box(handles, labels, markerfirst)
    585 tmp = self._loc_used_default
    586 self._set_loc(loc)

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py:867, in Legend._init_legend_box(self, handles, labels, markerfirst)
    864         text_list.append(textbox._text)
    865         # Create the artist for the legend which represents the
    866         # original artist/handle.
--> 867         handle_list.append(handler.legend_artist(self, orig_handle,
    868                                                  fontsize, handlebox))
    869         handles_and_labels.append((handlebox, textbox))
    871 columnbox = []

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py:130, in HandlerBase.legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox)
    106 """
    107 Return the artist that this HandlerBase generates for the given
    108 original artist/handle.
   (...)
    123 
    124 """
    125 xdescent, ydescent, width, height = self.adjust_drawing_area(
    126          legend, orig_handle,
    127          handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent,
    128          handlebox.width, handlebox.height,
    129          fontsize)
--> 130 artists = self.create_artists(legend, orig_handle,
    131                               xdescent, ydescent, width, height,
    132                               fontsize, handlebox.get_transform())
    134 # create_artists will return a list of artists.
    135 for a in artists:

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py:496, in HandlerRegularPolyCollection.create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans)
    490 ydata = self.get_ydata(legend, xdescent, ydescent,
    491                        width, height, fontsize)
    493 sizes = self.get_sizes(legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent,
    494                        width, height, fontsize)
--> 496 p = self.create_collection(
    497     orig_handle, sizes,
    498     offsets=list(zip(xdata_marker, ydata)), offset_transform=trans)
    500 self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
    501 p.set_offset_transform(trans)

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py:297, in rename_parameter..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    292     warn_deprecated(
    293         since, message=f"The {old!r} parameter of {func.__name__}() "
    294         f"has been renamed {new!r} since Matplotlib {since}; support "
    295         f"for the old name will be dropped %(removal)s.")
    296     kwargs[new] = kwargs.pop(old)
--> 297 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Users\z004eeud\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py:511, in HandlerPathCollection.create_collection(self, orig_handle, sizes, offsets, offset_transform)
    508 @_api.rename_parameter("3.6", "transOffset", "offset_transform")
    509 def create_collection(self, orig_handle, sizes, offsets, offset_transform):
    510     return type(orig_handle)(
--> 511         [orig_handle.get_paths()[0]], sizes=sizes,
    512         offsets=offsets, offset_transform=offset_transform,
    513     )

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Need a solution for analyzing more data.